Using &, or =CONCAT and losing a 0 (not a leading 0)
In Excel, I am trying to add 4 cells together into one. Example the numbersin cells A1:11, B1:21, C1:04, D1:66 to get result in cel E1: 11210466. I am have tried using &, as well as =CONCAT. The result always loses the 0 to get 1121466. Help?
I am have tried using &, as well as =CONCAT. The result always loses the 0 to get 1121466. Help? (IM trying to invert  Hexadecimal number)

Use TEXT to retain the 0. That is a leading 0 btw.

Please try: =CONCAT(BASE(A1:D1,10,2)) as mentioned above its a leading 0 possible it is formatted as TEXT or Custom Formatted to show leading 0s

Try using TEXT() or BASE() functions:


=CONCAT(BASE(A1:D1,10,2))


Or, Use something like this to make it dynamic and keep leading zeros for the max len of a number:
=CONCAT(TEXT(A1:D1,REPT(0,MAX(LEN(A1:D1)))))


Or,
=CONCAT(BASE(A1:D1,10,MAX(LEN(A1:D1))))


